# How to get the lines with a cursor programatically in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I know I can get a single line doing this:

```
editor.document.lineAt(editor.selection.active.line).text
```

But I'm wondering how to do the equivalent when I have multiple cursors. I haven't found any reference to multiline cursors in the [API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the docs for `selection`:

> The primary selection on this text editor. Shorthand for `TextEditor.selections[0]`.

If there are multiple cursors, the `selections` array will simply have more than one element.